# Can we add our own environmental labels in MLflow?

Tags: environment-variables, mlflow

There are certain default inbuilt system tags in mlflow to set certain values. But is possible to set our own environment labels in mlflow like training, testing etc.?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the environment labels, like example usage, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by environment labels, but perhaps you can group runs into an experiment

```py
training_experiment = mlflow.set_experiment("training")
with mlflow.start_run(experiment_id=training_experiment.experiment_id):
        ...
```

Another approach would be to use the mlflow project component and have a **MLProject** file like this:

```
name: Example

conda_env: environment.yaml

entry_points:
  # train Keras DL model
  train:
    parameters:
      training_data: {type: string, default: "<some_path>"}
      epochs: {type: int, default: 32}
    command: "python train.py {training_data}
                                    --epochs {epochs}
```

The argument passing can be done with click or using the standard argument passing in python.